# VB5 application using DAO on access2000 mdb file, gettings 3218 error from time to time

Tags: dao

I'm dealing with a legacy application (vb5.0) which access an access2000 mdb file on a file server, using DAO. I use Jet4.0

Many of my clients have this application and they all get 3218 errors from time to time. I'm talking about small networks of 2-3 PCs.

Here's how it works: a form is opened (no bound controls), user enters data and then he presses "SAVE": At that point, there is a rs.Edit invoked, fields are updated and there is a rs.Update. So the record is locked instantly.

A 3218 error appears very often.

How is that possible, since locking is only instantly happening and it's practically impossible for two users to press SAVE in the same time!

PS - Updating to something more modern is not an option...!

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks for nobody answering. 
Anyway, I solved my problem after spliting the mdb file